# textArea (or HtmlEditor) extJS (+ruby on rails 2.3.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs

I have `text area`, i write something there for example:

```
hello
All
People!
```

in controller I use command named gsub (for example i write .gsub("\n", "
") to replace "\n" with ). In my database I see

```
hello
All
People!
```

its Ok. Next when I trying to update my textarea, I have something like this:

```
hello<br>
All<br>
People!<br>
```

How to avoid this? I dont want this br's in my textarea. Maybe i can change or replace in controller again?

Thank yoU!

I tried to htmleditor, but nothing i cant paste in my project (not clickable) :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace `<br>` tags with `\n`. You can do it with this regex `#<br\s*?/?>#i`

Comment: oh , thanks for advise!, this regex i should write below the textarea yes?

Comment: You should run it on your string when you take it from your database. I just don't know how to write it in ruby. But the idea is just to replace `<br>` tags in your string with `\n`.

Comment: mm, write it only in ruby or in extJS?

Comment: how you put your string in the textarea?

Look you did this `.gsub("\n", "<br>")` right? So now when you take it from your database you have to do the opposite `.gsub("<br>", "\n")`